# translate runtime addresses in GDB

Tags: debugging, memory, gdb, mapping

When I run process with GDB and the process is not running I always get same address for same function. However when I run the process I get different address every time.
How can I compare addresses from 2 runs of the same process? ( the binary does not contain debug symbols )

Comment: When you run under gdb, aslr is disabled by default. When you run without, aslr is enabled. Therefore you get different addresses every time.

Answer (score 0):

when process runs there is dynamic memory mapping that may change every time you run the process.
to watch it simply use the gdb command :
"info proc mapping"
another way to see memory mapping is bash "pmap" command.

each mapping region has start address and size , if you reduce the start address from the runtime address you will get the same address that you get when gdb is not running , which is always the same address.

little example:

mapping output looks like this :

```
     *Start Addr           End Addr       Size     Offset objfile
  0x563d17d8c000     0x563d17fd2000   0x246000        0x0 /opt/redislabs/bin/dmcproxy
  0x563d181d2000     0x563d181d8000     0x6000   0x246000 /opt/redislabs/bin/dmcproxy
  0x563d181d8000     0x563d181ee000    0x16000   0x24c000 /opt/redislabs/bin/dmcproxy*
```

you get the address 0x0000563d17ed13fa on runtime.
in order to translate it to program address you should reduce its start address , start address is 0x563d17fd2000 so result address is 0x1453fa

--> this is the address you have in the binary code , if it is an address of a funtion you can see it using objdump or by running gdb without running the program.

if the binary you run is stripped and you have unstripped version of the same binary on different machine you can now use the calculated address to see details about the address you found by running gdb on the unstripped binary ( without running the process ) and use:
"info symbol 0x1453fa"
it will work even if you are in the middle of a function
( note that backtraces will give you the return address and not the function address which is usually different )

Comment: For everyone that also tries to understand the addresses in this example. 0x563d17fd2000 is the end address. To get the correct result address you' need the start address 0x563d17d8c000 and calculate 0x0000563d17ed13fa - 0x563d17d8c000 => 0x1453fa. And use the one from the row where your address is in between start and end. And add the offset at the end.